# undefined within the react component - but not in action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Have a call to action (backend call) response is some array - getting undefined here - in few other cases where I am mapping over the array I am seeing map of undefined error as well. Is componentDidMount right place to put such calls?

I get the response back when I console log in action creator before dispatching.

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.props.fetchData(test, foo);
    console.log(this.props.responseData); //getting here undefined
  }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    responseData: state.abc.responseData,
  };
}

Mycomp.propTypes = {
  responseData: React.PropTypes.array,
  fetchData: React.PropTypes.func,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Mycomp);
```

Comment: presumably `fetchData` is asynchronous right? so it won't be available on the next line like that

Comment: see this question and accepted answer. I think you will find it helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381378/whats-the-best-way-to-deal-with-undefined-props-in-react-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is undefined because the request has not been made at the time you're trying to log the response – it's async.

You can either call the action in here:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchData(test, foo);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  if (props.responseData) { console.log(props.responseData); } // should be getting the data if the request works
}
```

or define a callback that is executed *after* the request was successful.

Comment: yes you are right, I see the value now in the <div>{this.props.data}</div> I am seeing an error just before for a fraction of second I am seeing error screen 'undefined' - how do I make sure in reactjs if props is not empty...how to add props. responseData to constructor/getInitialstate etc.,?

Comment: Try `<div>{this.props.data ? this.props.data : ''}</div>`. Basically you want to check if it's undefined, if not show it.

Comment: tried that, i still see the red screen for a second before the page loads - and an error message....bundle.js:76754 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined(…)

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the render method? Or are you using `this.props.data` anywhere else before it's actually there?

Comment: hey sorry my bad, i was checking for an internal value in the if - not the high level object - working for me now..thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `fetchData()` is returning `Promise` which is `async`

So you can get data from `componentWillReceiveProps()` which is called when ever you have new props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   console.log(nextProps.responseData); //do whatever you want with response
}
```

Since `componentDidMount()` is called at only once. It's not reliable place to do something with your `props`.