# React Router and Redux - Data on initial load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have looked a lot of questions and answers on the site concerning an issue that I am experiencing.

I have the usual setup with React, React Router and Redux.  My top level component is as follows.

```
// Imports

const reducers = {
  main: baseReducer,
  form: formReducer,
};

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
);

store.dispatch(actions.auth.setCurrentUser());
// store.dispatch(actions.api.fetchLineup());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Inside my App.jsx I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from './Main';

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Main />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

My Main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import GroupingContainer from '../containers/Grouping';
import HomeContainer from '../containers/Home';

const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomeContainer} />
      <Route path='/groupings/:id' component={GroupingContainer} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
);

export default Main;
```

And finally I have my Grouping.jsx and GroupingContainer.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function loadGrouping(props, groupingId) {
  const grouping = props.main.groupings.find(
    (g) => g.id === groupingId
  );
  if (!grouping) {
    props.dispatch(api.fetchGrouping(groupingId));
  }
}

class Grouping extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    loadGrouping(props, props.groupingId);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('Next: ', nextProps);
    if (nextProps.match && nextProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
      loadGrouping(this.props, nextProps.groupingId);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const grouping = this.props.main.groupings.find(
      (lg) => lg.id === this.props.groupingId
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{grouping.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Grouping;
```

GroupingContainer.jsx

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Grouping from '../components/Grouping';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    groupingId: parseInt(ownProps.match.params.id, 10),
    ...state,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  dispatch,
});

const GroupingContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Grouping);

export default GroupingContainer;
```

After the request it fires another action that adds the returned grouping to the store and into an array of groups `state.main.groups`

I am having 2 problems.  When I browse from the root path to one of the groupings, the following flow:

```
http://localhost:3000 -> http://localhost:3000/#/groupings/19
```

I receive the message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` for a brief second until the API request finishes and populates the `{grouping.name}` and when I do a complete refresh of the page on a grouping URL `http://localhost:3000/#/groupings/19` the application does not load at all and gives them same `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I have been using React for around 2 months and have really started using API requests on Component loads.  I can not really figure out where to place the API request properly to prevent the view rendering before it has finished and erroring out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: see this post it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381378/whats-the-best-way-to-deal-with-undefined-props-in-react-js  I asked a question similar and got a very cool response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change render of Grouping Component like this.

```
render() {
    const grouping = this.props.main.groupings.find(
      (lg) => lg.id === this.props.groupingId
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{grouping ? grouping.name : ""}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Omg, thanks, what a stupid overlook as well.  You saved some frustration.  Thanks!